# Table columns are out of bounds

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

odoo users.
This is part of my Qweb report:

```
 <table class="table-metal">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-transform: none;width:20%">Name</th>
            <th style="text-transform: none;width:30%">Width</th>
            <th style="text-transform: none;width:20%">Mark</th>
            <th style="text-transform: none;width:20%">Standard</th>
            <th style="text-transform: none;width:10%">Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <t t-set="node_name_value" t-value="noname"/>
        <t t-foreach="doc.passport_metal_ids" t-as="metal_ids">
            <tr>
                <t t-if="metal_ids.product_name.name != node_name_value">
                    <t t-set="count" t-value="doc.get_count_row(metal_ids.product_name.name)"/>
                    <td valign="top" t-att-rowspan="count"><span t-field="metal_ids.product_name.name" /></td>
                </t>
                <t t-if="metal_ids.brand_id.name[0] == 'S'">
                    <td>Лист S=<span t-esc="metal_ids.size_id.name.split('x')[0]" /></td>
                </t>
                <t t-else="">
                    <td>Лист B-PN-0 S=<span t-esc="metal_ids.size_id.name.split('x')[0]" /><br></br>ГОСТ 19903-74 </td>
                </t>
                <td><span t-field="metal_ids.brand_id.name" /></td>
                <td><span t-field="metal_ids.gost_id.name" /></td>
                <td><span t-field="metal_ids.certificate" /></td>
                <t t-set="node_name_value" t-value="metal_ids.product_name.name"/>
            </tr>
        </t>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"></td>
        </tr>

    </tfoot>


</table>
<p style="page-break-after:always;"></p>
```

Because of the dynamic column:

```
<td valign="top" t-att-rowspan="count"><span t-field="metal_ids.product_name.name" /></td>
```

I get the following:

[image]

I added , but it did not help

Table columns are out of bounds. How to fix it?

Comment: I added <tfoot>, but it did not help  (remark)